# woocommerce add to cart issue in cordova

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, phonegap, woocommerce-rest-api

i am developing a cordova  app based on woocommerce website. woocommerce REST APIs not providing cart APIs so we used custom code to add products to cart.
product added successfully to cart but cart are common to all users. if person 1 add a product to cart the same product added to all the other app users. How can i solve this??

my PHP code is

```php
require('../wp-load.php');
global $wpdb;
$id = $_POST['user'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if (empty($id)) {
  exit;
}
$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = $username;
$creds['user_password'] = $password;
$creds['remember'] = true;
$user = wp_signon($creds, false);
//print_r($user);
wp_clear_auth_cookie();
wp_set_current_user($id, $password);
wp_set_auth_cookie($id, true, false);
$addcart = WC() - > cart - > add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $arrayvariation, $cartmeta);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this one depends on PHP code. You should not give same cart to all users , so your SQL query should controle cart for each user.

For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user = '$userID'";
```

I think you where wrong there, maybe you did selecting data without controling for which one user.